# How to Route to Nested Area Using Razor Pages Tag Helpers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Environment:
Visual Studio 2019 16.5.4
.NET Core 3.1
Razor Pages

I have a nested area such that the directory structure looks like this:

```
/Areas
/Areas/customer
/Areas/customer/Pages
/Areas/customer/Pages/index.cshtml
/Areas/customer/Pages/create.cshtml
/Areas/customer/Pages/note
/Areas/customer/Pages/note/index.cshtml
/Areas/customer/Pages/note/create.cshtml
```

I am trying to figure out how to route to the nested area of `note` using the `asp-page` and `asp-area` tag helpers. I never get any content in the `href` portion of the anchor tag. Here is the Razor Pages syntax I am using (I based this on the Identity scaffolded code):

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-area="customer" asp-page="/note" asp-route-CustomerId="@item.Id"><span class="btn-label-sm"><i class="fas fa-sticky-note"></i></span>Notes</a>
```

I have tried lots of different combinations of `asp-page` and `asp-area` with no luck. If I generate the `href` myself it works:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/customer/note?id=@item.Id"><span class="btn-label-sm"><i class="fas fa-sticky-note"></i></span>Notes</a>
```

I just want to know why the tag helpers are not working and if I am doing something wrong with nested areas or configuring the routes.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The tag helper default  are specifically discovered under paths that look like /Areas/{AreaName}/Pages/  .

Comment: Yes, and those are working fine. Maybe they are not capable of handling `/Areas/{AreaName}/Pages/{NestedAreaName}/`? I know that Identity has the following `/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage`. And once you are in a nested area, the tag helpers work fine because they are relative links within the same area.

Comment: @Psyfun Were you able to solve the problem? I'm having the same issue in the areas folder.

Comment: For the areas that were not working, I am simply generating the direct link rather than using the helpers. I am assuming that a future fix will address the problem as there's a lot of development still happening in Asp.Net Core and Razor Pages.